# unable to parse text from pre with php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am unable to parse the text in the link using my php. It gives the error trying to get the property of a non-object. anyone know what's wrong?

```
$html = file_get_html('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20|%20Aquamarine%20Revenge%20%28Battle-Scarred%29');
$ret = $html->find('pre',0)->plaintext;
echo $ret;
```

Comment: Paste the exact error.   Do a var_dump on the supposed "object".

Comment: That URL returns JSON, not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the URL doesn't actually have a `<pre>` - it's straight json.

Your browser puts the content inside a `<pre>` to make it display properly to you, but that information doesn't actually come form the URL.

e: To make this more useful...

```
$ret = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20|%20Aquamarine%20Revenge%20%28Battle-Scarred%29');
echo $ret;
```

Then if you want to actually use the returned data...

```
$json = json_decode($ret);
```